# Windows Azure VM with teamviewer installed is accessable only when RDP is connected and maximized

Tags: azure, teamviewer

I've created an Azure VM with Windows server 2016, and I have teamviewer installed. I want to be able to access the VM via Teamviewer, however, if I am not connected to the VM by Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP), then my teamviewer listing for the Azure VM shows as offline. If I connect to the VM via RDP, it comes online.

If I connect with Teamviewer, and then minimize the RDP connection, I get a message:

"Teamviewer the screen cannot be captured at the moment, this is probably due to fast user switching or a minimized or disconnected rdp session."

In order to prevent this, I've already searched a lot of related questions, and tried the following:

In GPEDIT.MSC, edited the Remote Desktop Session Host > Session Time Limits to Enabled and Never to disconnect

[image]

In Local Security Policy, set Interactive Logon: Do not require CTRL+ ALT+DEL to Enabled

[image]

In Teamviewer, in Options > Advanced, enabled "Enhanced multi user support (For Terminal Server)" and "Full access control when a partner is connecting to the windows logon screen"

[image]

Is there any way I can make Teamviewer accessable on the VM regardless of RDP status?

Comment: Any reason using Teamviewer when you have a built in tool that works perfectly ?

Comment: Teamviewer is more flexible for my organization in a number of different ways, for example, drag and drop file transfer, much easier to create temporary access for other parties who might need to log in to look at/fix one particular issue, remote printing, and for consistency, since teamviewer is the standard remote access tool at our organization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just use the Server ID and no the User ID.
[image]

Already tested and worked fine for me

Comment: Yes, this is the answer, worked right away. Not sure why this was so difficult to find out, maybe I was just asking the wrong questions on google. Thanks heaps.

Comment: It frustrates me no end that they don't show the sever ID on the main TeamViewer window.  It is also tedious that the text and window size they chose in the popup has the server ID  *always* wrap over two lines.

A cent for each of the times I've had an IT person blindly give me the user ID instead of the server ID because nothing indicated there were 2x IDs would let me retire early.